# What is the cleanest way to instantiate multiple UIViews from one .xib file in swift

Tags: ios, swift

My goal is to store 3 very similar views in one .xib file.

I have one view controller, one class that creates/handles the views, and my xib file.  This code is fully functioning but what bothers me about it is the way we reference UIViews blindly in an array with [0],[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14GaG.jpg)], and [2], then we depend on our cast to be sure we have the right view. We may have many variations of these views which will be annoying to count and verify the type of each one before using.

I would like to have this code be simplified in such a way where I can instantiate the views directly based on their class name.

Here is my example:

ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()     
        self.view.addSubview(TestView1.instanceFromNib())
        self.view.addSubview(TestView2.instanceFromNib())
        self.view.addSubview(TestView3.instanceFromNib())
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

TestView.swift:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "View", bundle: nil)
class TestView1:UIView {
    class func instanceFromNib() -> TestView1 {
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! TestView1
    }
}
class TestView2:UIView{
    class func instanceFromNib() -> TestView2 {
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[1] as! TestView2
    }
}
class TestView3:UIView{
    class func instanceFromNib() -> TestView3 {
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[2] as! TestView3
    }
}
```

Test.xib:

[image: Test.xib]

Is there a better way to use UINib.instatiate()? Am I missing something? The only options I can seem to find are either split the views into multiple files or use this clunky array syntax.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: @Matt is correct. You haven't implied that you have more than 3 nibs. Maybe if there were a hundred - but then you have a much larger *design* issue - specifically "why" you've chosen this design. Probably the best alternative (for three or a handful) of files is to have a template file and do the rest in code. Or yeah, if you have two dozen screens, find what's common, turn them into templates, customize them in code (learning auto layout of course) and do it right!

Answer (score 2):

> My goal is to store 3 very similar views in one .xib file (so that I do not have tons of files clogging up my project).

Well, that's a bad idea. You're relying on a highly contingent fact; the truth is that you don't know which view is which, purely by index number, when they are loaded from the nib. Throw your fear of "tons of files clogging up my project" out the window; there was nothing to be afraid of in the first place. Store each view in its own *.xib* file. Problem solved; now you know that item `0` of the array loaded by UINib is the desired file. *That* is "cleanest".

Comment: This does not specifically solve my problem.  Given the requirements, do you have an actual answer? We have one large view with many small, simple subviews associated with it (~50).  Having 50 files for this is totally unnecessary. It's a valid question. I edited to make this more apparent.

Comment: "We have one large view with many small, simple subviews associated with it" Then why aren't those the subviews of that large view in _its_ nib?

Comment: However, loading 50 views at once is very heavyweight and defeats the purpose of nibs. 50 nibs would be better, because you only instantiate the view you _actually need_ at any one moment. Or maybe you don't need nibs at all; just have each view design itself in code. It seems like you are not grasping what nib-loading _is_: it's just a form of instantiation, exactly like saying `UIView()`.

Comment: Another idea: put them all in view controllers so you can put them in one storyboard. Load the desired view controller _by storyboard ID._ If you don't need the view controller for anything, grab the view; it isn't really right to use a view controller as a way of dumpster diving, but it does no harm in this case.